# Primefaces javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException during main screen to open new screen in new Window

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

Scenario:Total Two screen and both scoped are define @ViewScoped

Screen 1 into open window.open(screen.xhtml) screen and check some functionality into screen 2 and close screen 2 and after go to screen 1 and click on button then throw below error.

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /glb/GlbMbrReviewSubmissionWorkflow.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /glb/GlbMbrReviewSubmissionWorkflow.xhtml
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state of the view of each page is stored in the server (the default) in LRU map in session and the size is 15. Thenpage 1 view gets ejected out of map when the recent pages get viewed in page 2 more than 15 times. The solution approaches are,

1. Either you can increase the map size configurably to increase it but it increases the server memory load.
2. Or change the defaut state saving mechanism value to "client" but it increases network traffic .
3. One recommended solution is to poll the server from page 1 at specified no of seconds to bring the view on top of the map so it does not get deleted.

Comment: state saving mechanism value to "client" not working